# How to get specific value from data row while binding into a data list ? asp.net vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a data list control, inside of it I have two tables:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dataListAccount" runat ="server">                                                             
    <ItemTemplate  >                                                             
        <table runat ="server" id="tblAccountInfo">                                                                                                                    
            <tr>
                <td>                                         
                    Account Id: <%#Eval("AccountId")%> 
                </td>
            </tr>                                                                                
        </table>  
        <br>                                
        <table runat="server"  id ="tblAccountAmount" border="1">                                    
            <tr>
                <td><%#Eval("AccountBalance", "{0:C}")%></td>                                        
            </tr>                                   
        </table>                                                                                                            
    </ItemTemplate>                                                                                                            
</asp:DataList>
```

Then I populate the data list control with:

```
    'create datatable
    Dim dataTableAccount As DataTable = New DataTable()
    dataTableAccount.Columns.Add("AccountID")
    dataTableAccount.Columns.Add("AccountBalance")

    'populate data table
    Dim dataRow As DataRow = dataTableAccount.NewRow()
    dataRow(0) = 1 'Account ID
    dataRow(1) = 100 'Balance on the Account with Id=1
    dataTableAccount.Rows.Add(dataRow)

    Dim dataRow1 As DataRow = dataTableAccount.NewRow()
    dataRow1(0) = 2 'Account Id
    dataRow1(1) = 0 'Balance on the Account with Id=2
    dataTableAccount.Rows.Add(dataRow1)
    dataListAccount.DataSource = dataTableAccount
    dataListAccount.DataBind()
```

In the event dataListAccount_ItemDataBound I want to know how can I get the "AccounId" for the current item binding.

```
Private Sub dataListAccount_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As  
System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs) Handles 
dataListAccount.ItemDataBound

 Dim CurrentAccountId=  ???????

End Sub
```

Comment: I think i found one way to do it:                                                                                                            Dim currentRowBinding As System.Data.DataRowView = CType(e.Item.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView)
        Dim currentAccountId = currentRowBinding("AccountId")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found one way to do it:

```
Dim currentRowBinding As System.Data.DataRowView = CType(e.Item.DataItem,   System.Data.DataRowView)

Dim currentAccountId = currentRowBinding("AccountId")
```

Answer (score 0):

Better put value into label

```
Account Id: <asp:label id="lblAccountID" runat="server" Text ='<%#Eval("AccountId")%>' />
```

On code behind, you can easy to find it use

```
Dim CurrentAccountId =  e.item.FindControl("lblAccountID")
```